# How to represent the following rails models / assocs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have the following models:

- Client   #These represent 3rd party entities
- GroupCo  #Individual companies within the group
- Supplier #These are 3rd party entities.
- Invoice  #This could be one of : GroupCo to Client, GroupCo to other GroupCo, Supplier to GroupCo

Under normal circumstances I would just have a ClientInv model and a SupplierInv model depending on whether the Invoice is to a Client or From a Supplier.  The problem arising here is where GroupCo bills to another GroupCo.  In this case the first GroupCo acts as Supplier and 2nd as Client and I need to keep a single Invoice sequence for each GroupCo regardless of whether they are billing Clients or other GroupCos.... so that's why I think I can't split my Invoice model.

This is not a particularly unusual situation so I'm hoping that someone will have done this already.

Currently I'm open to any / all suggestions including completely different models if necessary.

I'm on Rails 3.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt's suggestion has helped me to solve this.  Remember that my main problem with the Polymorphic invoice was getting to the Invoice from GroupCo both as a Client and as a Supplier.  So this is how I did it.

Invoice has the following attribs:

invclient_type

invclient_id

invsupp_type

invsupp_id

---

Invoice has the following associations

belongs_to :invclient, polymorphic: true

belongs_to :invsupp, polymorphic: true

---

GroupCo has the following associations

has_many  :clientinvoices, class_name: :Invoice, as: :invclient

has_many  :suppinvoices, class_name: :Invoice, as: :invsupp

---

With the above in place I can do the following with an instance of GroupCo (gco)

gco.clientinvoices
gco.suppinvoices

and with an instance of Invoice (inv) I can do the usual to get to the belongs_to

inv.invclient to get to the Client of the invoice
inv.invsupp to get to the Supplier of the invoice

Comment: Since Matt's answer lead you to the solution, would you accept his answer, by clicking the tick mark? Or, at least, giving him an upvote? It seems to be kind to offer credit where it is due.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're describing, where a `GroupCo` can get invoices as well as clients is generally solvable through inheritance. `Client` needs to inherit from `Company`, `GroupCo` needs to inherit from `Company`. Then you can send an invoice to a `Company` and then the system doesn't care if you're talking about a `GroupCo` or `Client`.

However giving you a specific answer is going to be hard because it looks like you don't really grok the domain problem of invoicing yet. For example where you talk about a `ClientInv` Model and a `SupplierInv` Model makes me think you're approaching this problem entirely the wrong way.

They're both invoices, just ones to the system and ones from the system. But they are both invoices. You will have to deal with Credit Notes and Purchase Orders soon as well as all the other fun things involved with invoicing, you don't want to be duplicating everything.

I also seriously recommend you stop shortening your Class names, it's a bad habit for larger enterprise apps. Call a `GroupCompany` what is is. And `SupplierInvoice`. And `ClientInvoice`.

Comment: I am happy to have a single Invoice model in polymorphic form as:

Comment: I am happy to have a single Invoice model in polymorphic form as: Invoice belongs_to inv, polymorphic: true and Client has_many :invoices, as :inv and GroupCo has_many :invoices, as :inv.  This association would represent GroupCo as a 'client' of that invoice.  However GroupCo also has_many :invoices from a Supplier point of view.  How do I represent that?  I already have a flag to denote whether it is an Invoice or Credit Note.  Also I take the point about shortening names.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Ahh, ok, sounds like you understand it pretty well. I'd just split them into something like sent_inv and received_inv or something like that. So supplier only has sent, client received and GroupCo has both. There's probably a better word for them in invoicing terms but it's been a while since I worked with invoicing systems :) Thankfully!

Comment: Yeah I see where you are coming from but when GroupCo has both how do I access sent_inv and received_inv types from GroupCo. If I had an instance of GroupCo called gco and I tried to do gco.invoices (which I believe is all that's available) then which association will Rails go through?  Perhaps there is some way of getting to sent and received invoices that I don't know about but perhaps you do.... I'm hoping.  Regarding Invoicing systems...I was an accountant in my previous life!!